# tomcat6 manager

Tags: server, tomcat

I've just installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server with LAMP support. Tomcat6 seems to run ok. But, I am unable to get into the manager-webapp...  I've updated the tomcat-users.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<tomcat-users>

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager,admin"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager,admin"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

But, no matter what I try, it keeps rejecting my username/password combo.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've done what I did - put your own roles into the example section. The problem (for me at least) was that the example section is commented out. Make sure that you put your config outside the comment section.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In those cases usually you have to restart tomcat `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart` will do,otherwise restart Ubuntu.And check if the role/user tags are inside the comments as @spinlock said.